# Weka: loading CSV file without headers

Tags: csv, weka

How to load a CSV file without headers in Weka?

There are a few related questions, but none seems to get to the point.

**MWE**

Here is the `test.csv` file:

```
20,1,"+"
30,2,"+"
30,1,"+"
15,1,"-"
10,0,"-"
```

Here is the `Test.java` code:

```
// javac -Xlint -cp weka.jar Test.java && java -cp .:weka.jar Test

import weka.core.converters.CSVLoader;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import java.io.File;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
            loader.setOptions(new String[] {"-H"});
            loader.setSource(new File("test.csv"));

            Instances tr = loader.getDataSet();
            tr.setClassIndex(tr.numAttributes() - 1);

            Classifier m = (Classifier) new NaiveBayes();
            m.buildClassifier(tr);

            Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(tr);
            eval.evaluateModel(m, tr);

            System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString());
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

When running, it only reports **4** instances, not **5**. If I add headers, then it works correctly.

```
Correctly Classified Instances           4              100      %
Incorrectly Classified Instances         0                0      %
Kappa statistic                          1     
Mean absolute error                      0.0065
Root mean squared error                  0.0112
Relative absolute error                  1.3088 %
Root relative squared error              2.2477 %
Total Number of Instances                4
```

Notice I have used:

```
            loader.setOptions(new String[] {"-H"});
```

I have also tried the direct API `loader.setNoHeaderRowPresent(true);`, but it seems to not be available in Weka 3.6.13.

References:

- [CSVLoader API](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/CSVLoader.html)

**EDIT:** It turns out this was a problem in 3.6.13. The code works fine for 3.7.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about 3.6.13, but the code for 3.7.10 shows that first row of data is added if setNoHeaderRowPresent is set  **true**.

You are setting false, set it to true.Refrence from [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/pentaho/pentaho.weka/pdm-3.7-ce/3.7.10/weka/core/converters/CSVLoader.java#CSVLoader.0m_noHeaderRow) of CSVLoader

> Set whether there is no header row in the data.
>    Parameters: b **true** if
>   there is no header row in the data
>      public void setNoHeaderRowPresent(boolean b) {
>        m_noHeaderRow = b; 293
>   }

```
if (m_noHeaderRow) {    
  m_rowBuffer.add(firstRow);  
 }
```

So in your code use

```
loader.setNoHeaderRowPresent(true)
```

and not **loader.setNoHeaderRowPresent(false)** to include first row in data set.

Comment: Thanks, I read the documentation too rapidly. But the thing is that it does not seem to be implemented for 3.6.13: `Test.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
            loader.setNoHeaderRowPresent(true);`. But it's weird that `loader.setOptions(new String[] {"-H"});` does not work for me either. I am posting a workaround as an alternative answer...

Comment: Okay, I have tried the developer version 3.7.10, and both versions work: either the `setNoHeaderRowPresent()` and `setOption()`. Seems like a bug from the stable version 3.6.13. http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/downloading.html

Comment: I'm on `3.8.4` and I am trying to open the `CSV` header-less file with the `Explorer` GUI application. Even specifying the `setNoHeaderRowPresent` as `true` is not working or giving "Invalid stream header" errors.

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around, this reads the CSV file and passes it along as an ARFF file:

```
// javac -Xlint -cp weka.jar Test.java && java -cp .:weka.jar Test

import weka.core.converters.CSVLoader;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.lang.StringBuffer;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String filename = "test.csv";
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            String line = br.readLine();
            int cols = line.length() - line.replace(",", "").length() + 1;

            StringBuilder arff = new StringBuilder("@RELATION test\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < cols-1; i++) {
                arff.append("@ATTRIBUTE ");
                arff.append(String.valueOf((char)(i + 'a')));
                arff.append(" NUMERIC\n");
            }
            arff.append("@ATTRIBUTE class {+,-}\n");
            arff.append("@DATA\n");

            while(line != null) {
                arff.append(line);
                arff.append("\n");
                line = br.readLine();
            }

            System.out.println(arff.toString());
            Instances tr = new Instances(new StringReader(arff.toString()));

            tr.setClassIndex(tr.numAttributes() - 1);

            Classifier m = (Classifier) new NaiveBayes();
            m.buildClassifier(tr);

            Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(tr);
            eval.evaluateModel(m, tr);

            System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString());
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Naruto, it's a hack obviously, and it's a MWE hack. I cannot edit the original CSV files if that's what you're suggesting. This model has to be integrated into the rest of our research framework, which includes other languages. We are not going to edit CSV files just for one Weka model.